Pycharm keeps updating interpreter on Jupyter Notebook only
When I open any Jupyter notebook in Pycharm, at the bottom on the left there are two processes running: updating python interpreter and uploading pycharm helpers.
I use a remote interpreter, and before recently these processes ran one time when opening a notebook, now they run constantly and a window pops up every 3 seconds with connecting to server... which is very annoying.
This happens only when jupyter notebooks are open and dissapears when I open a .py file.
enter image description here
Pycharm version: 2024.1.2
Python version (remote): 3.11.9
Python version (local): 3.12.3
I tried:

updating Pycharm (didn't work),
restarting interpreter (worked at first but problem remained upon restarting)


So it turned out it was some sort of a bug. To solve this problem, you need to to these steps:

Go to interpreter settings
Click on button "test connection"
Save

It worked for me. But you need to do that every time when restarting Pycharm.
